# SQLAlchemy only POST has any effect

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to build a simple football players REST API with Flask and SQLAlchemy.
Only POST has an effect on the database though. PUT and DELETE complete successfully, but have no effect. What to do?

```
@app.route('/players', methods=['POST'])
def create_player():
    try:
        if not request.is_json or 'id' not in request.get_json():
            return bad_request("Request is a valid json: "+str(request.is_json))
        r = request.get_json()
        r['last_modified'] = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        player = Player(**r)
        db.session.add(player)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({'player': player.serialize}), 201
    except(TypeError):
        return not_found("Invalid input data.")

@app.route('/players/<id>', methods=['PUT'])
def update_player(id):
    try:
        Player.query.filter_by(id=id).update(request.get_json())
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        player = Player.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
        player.last_modified = str(now)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({'player': player.serialize}), 201
    except:
        return not_found("Player does not exist")

@app.route('/players/<id>', methods=["DELETE"])
def delete_player(id):
    try:
        Player.query.filter_by(id=id).delete()
        db.session.commit()
        return 'deleted'
    except:
        return not_found("Player does not exist.")
```

Here are logger results of POST, PUT, DELETE in succession:

```
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:select version()
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[raw sql] {}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:select current_schema()
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[raw sql] {}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:show standard_conforming_strings
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[raw sql] {}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:INSERT INTO player (id, first_name, last_name, current_club, nationality, date_of_birth, preferred_position, last_modified) VALUES (%(id)s, %(first_name)s, %(last_name)s, %(current_club)s, %(nationality)s, %(date_of_birth)s, %(preferred_position)s, %(last_modified)s)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[generated in 0.00019s] {'id': 9, 'first_name': 'marko4', 'last_name': 'markovic', 'current_club': 'dinamo', 'nationality': 'croatia', 'date_of_birth': '01.01.1970.', 'preferred_position': 'ATK', 'last_modified': '2021-06-18 06:49:38.131088'}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:COMMIT
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:SELECT player.id AS player_id, player.first_name AS player_first_name, player.last_name AS player_last_name, player.current_club AS player_current_club, player.nationality AS player_nationality, player.date_of_birth AS player_date_of_birth, player.preferred_position AS player_preferred_position, player.last_modified AS player_last_modified 
FROM player 
WHERE player.id = %(pk_1)s
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[generated in 0.00017s] {'pk_1': 9}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:ROLLBACK
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2021 06:49:38] "POST /players HTTP/1.1" 201 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2021 06:49:38] "POST /players HTTP/1.1" 201 -
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:UPDATE player SET preferred_position=%(preferred_position)s WHERE player.id = %(id_1)s
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[generated in 0.00017s] {'preferred_position': 'ATK', 'id_1': '9'}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:SELECT player.id AS player_id, player.first_name AS player_first_name, player.last_name AS player_last_name, player.current_club AS player_current_club, player.nationality AS player_nationality, player.date_of_birth AS player_date_of_birth, player.preferred_position AS player_preferred_position, player.last_modified AS player_last_modified 
FROM player 
WHERE player.id = %(id_1)s 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[generated in 0.00014s] {'id_1': '9', 'param_1': 1}
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2021 06:50:01] "PUT /players/9 HTTP/1.1" 201 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2021 06:50:01] "PUT /players/9 HTTP/1.1" 201 -
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:DELETE FROM player WHERE player.id = %(id_1)s
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[generated in 0.00016s] {'id_1': '6'}
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2021 06:50:48] "DELETE /players/6 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2021 06:50:48] "DELETE /players/6 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are hiding all of your exceptions. This makes debugging next to impossible. You should log them probably.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include helper methods, which include printing of stack trace. Still, no exceptions are found.

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of `db`? I.e. is the `db` you used to build your models the same you use in your routes? If not, then you are emitting changes in one session, but commit in another.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see a commit log in your sqlalchemy logs. You are not committing your changes correctly. You have to do your changes commit within a atomic block

```
with appcontext:
   change1
   change2
```

Look here for more https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/contexts/

Comment: I agree, but how to do it then? I am using `db.session.commit()` every time.

Comment: you have to do it within a atomic block. see my edits

Comment: Unfortunately adding `with app.app_context():` had the same effect.

Comment: can you use `db.session.delete(me)` instead of `Player.query.filter_by(id=id).delete()` and try

Comment: When using `db.session.delete(player)` i get: `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<Player at 0x7f5547b18358>' is already attached to session '1' (this is '2')
`

Comment: there is a problem with the way you are managing sessions. you should try to use contextual sessions

Comment: I just do not understand why POST would work then.

Comment: thats because its the first step and then you mess up your sessions.